# Front driveshafts on landrover defender don't stay in place

Tags: technic, instructions, gears, vehicle

The front driveshafts on my [Land Rover Defender](https://brickset.com/sets/42110-1/Land-Rover-Defender) keep falling out, then the cogs fall out of the front differential. I have done them three times as per the manual, but every time I get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post some pictures of problematic place within your suspension assembly?

Comment: Thanks Alex - in the middle of last night i discovered the problem. You have to click the hubs together and then it works. Now though i have the same problem as others i see here, with the front wheels turning one way and the back wheels the other.

Comment: Your trouble is most likely explained in https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10780/9398-4x4-crawler-front-wheels-rotate-in-the-opposite-direction-to-the-rear-wheel . In case you face other issues you should raise them as a separate question.